How can I find team member's Out of Office schedule programmatically
I'm trying to create team schedule.
I would like to find team member's Out of Office schedule
so that I can create schedule table who will be in office or absent.
I tried Outlook VBA, Graph API.
But none of above doesn't work.

Please show us the code you have tried and why it didn't work as you woul like. Add this to your post as formatted text

Exchange Web Services should do what you're looking for. You will need full access to their mailbox though.
Getting automatic reply information by using the EWS Managed API 2.0

In addition to EWS (which would require to register your app to use OAuth), you can retrieve f/b information in Outlook Object Model using Application.Session.CreateRecipient / Recipient.FreeBusy
